# After changing from sqlite to postgres (rails) destroy and edit are not working for my projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

So I am making a website(portfolio) for my projects, which has Projects, Contact, and a Devlog, in order for people to be able to follow my work and progress, but when I changed to postgres deployed to heroku somehow edit and destroy are no longer working.

Errors I am getting:

EDIT:

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer LINE 1: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (1) LIMIT 1 ^ : SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (1) LIMIT 1
```

DESTROY:

```
No route matches [POST] "/posts/1"
```

*This one apparently is trying to delete the posts (which are my devlogs)*

This is my Index of projects

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,400italic,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Marcos Collado - Graphic Designer/FrontEnd dev</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="selector_container">
                <%= image_tag("web.svg",:alt => "web",:id => 'web') %>
                <%= image_tag("logo.png",:alt => "logoSolstice",:id => 'logo') %>
                <%= image_tag("logo.png",:alt => "logoSolstice",:id => 'logo') %>

        </div>

        <h1 class=title>Projects</h1>
            <div id="project_wrap" class="skiny_wrap">
                <% @projects.each do |project|  %>
                        <div class="post">
                            <h2 class="name"><%= project.name %> </h2>
                            <p class="description"><%= project.description %> </p>

                            <% if project.has_photo? %>
                                        <a href="projects/<%=project.id%>">
                                            <div class="img_container" style="background-image: url(/photo_store/<%=project.id%>.<%=project.extension%>)"></div>
                                        </a>
                            <%else%>
                                <p> theres no image in here </p>
                            <%end%>

                            <p class="category"><%= project.category %> </p>
                            <p class="date"><%= project.created_at.strftime('%A, %B %d') %> </p>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                <%end%>

            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is my "show"

```
<div id="contact_wrap" class="skiny_wrap">


<br><br>

<h2><%=@project.name%></h2>
<br>
<div class="focus_photo">

</div>
<%=@project.link%>
<br><br>
<div class="focus_photo">

</div>
<%=@project.description%>
<br><br>
Theme: <%=@project.category%>
<br><br>
<div class="focus_photo">

</div>

<%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@project) %>
<%= link_to "Delete", post_path(@project), method: :delete, data:{ } %>

</div>
```

And this is my controller for projects

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_project, only: [:show,:edit,:update,:destroy]
    has_scope :by_category, type: :array

    def index
      @projects = apply_scopes(Project).all
      @project = Project.new
    end

    def new
      @project = Project.new
    end

    def create
      @project = Project.new project_params
        if @project.save
            redirect_to @project, notice:"Everything went all right, no need to worry"
        else
            render 'new', notice: "Oh no, How could we Screw up?!"
        end
    end

    def show
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
      unless @project
        render json: {error: "The project you are looking for doesn't seem to exist"},
        status: 404
        return
      end
    end

    def update
        if @project.update project_params
            redirect_to @project, notice: "we have an update working"
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
      @project.destroy
      redirect_to projects_path
    end

    private

    def find_project
        @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    def project_params
        params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, :link, :category, :photo)
    end

end
```

Comment: Any errors in heroku log

Comment: "Is not working" is probably the most useless information in the world. Check the logs.

Comment: the thing is, it is not working in local either anymore, thats why I didnt signal it as heroku. I think it is not needed to disqualify the information I provide with neither, very polite

Comment: If it isn't working locally in dev anymore then you should be able to get a stack trace at least. I think your first step should be to install PostgreSQL locally and develop/test on that; there are all kinds of differences between databases that ActiveRecord won't help you with, SQLite has a very loose interpretation of SQL but PostgreSQL has a very strict one.

Comment: I appreciate your aproach on the problem but precisely because I installed postgres locally I am having trouble destroying and editing

Comment: You have a miswritten scope or where query or a column with the wrong data type somewhere on that table. If it's happening on destroy and you have a `dependent: destroy` on another model, the issue could be there. Check your models, controllers, and views. @muistooshort is right. You've been "spoiled" (read: learned some bad habits) from SQLite. Don't worry. It happens to all of us.